# What determines how strong a fish is?

Tags: small-creek

Occasionally while fishing, I will get a message like this:

[image: fish was too strong]

What affects these events?  Do all instances of a single fish type have the same strength?  How can I lower the chance of these happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fish that is too strong for you is a direct result of you not having enough **Fishing Power** to do so.

You gain Fishing Power for, you guessed it, fishing more. So the more you fish, the more likely you have of catching harder fish, and more profit.

I am certain of this, as well as the fact that some fish are harder to catch than others. I experimented with this for a bit, and the fish that I got when I used the minnow for bait were a lot harder for me to catch then the ones I get by using the worms for bait. When I increased my fishing level I caught the Small-mouth Bass Fishes more frequently.

Comment: Does Fishing Pole level affect this at all?

Comment: @Batophobia Actually, I believe it to be directly correlated with fishing power, because every-time I gain a level in my fishing pole level my fishing power goes up.